# Print div without opening extra popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a GridView with a print button in the last column

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPrint" runat="server" Text="Print" OnClientClick="OnPrintClick(this);" OnClick="lnkPrint_Click"></asp:LinkButton>

function OnPrintClick(lnk)
{
    var row = lnk.parentNode.parentNode;        
    var userId = row.cells[0].innerHTML;      
    $('[id$=hdnPrintUserId]').val(userId);

    $('#<%=lblPrintIdNumber.ClientID %>').val("");
    $('#<%=lblPrintName.ClientID %>').val("");
    $('#<%=lblPrintAge.ClientID %>').val("");       

    $("#idPrint").show();
}
```

On click it opens a pop up which displays the user info :

```
<asp:Panel id="pnlPrintContents" runat = "server">
  <div id="idPrint" class="nicePanel panel panel-primary" style="display:none; position:absolute;left:10%;top:10%;margin-top:25px;">
    <div style="border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;overflow:auto">
      <div style="display:inline-block;padding:15px;width:280px;vertical-align:top;border-right:1px solid #eee;">
        <div>   
          <div>
            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Profile Photo"></asp:Label> </div>
          <div>
            <asp:Image style="max-height:100px;max-width:100px;" ID="profileImage" runat="server" />                
          </div>
          <hr />
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <asp:Label ID="lblIdNumber" runat="server" Text="Identification Number"></asp:Label> </div>
          <div>
            <asp:Label ID="lblPrintIdNumber" runat="server"></asp:Label> </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label> </div>
          <div><asp:Label ID="lblPrintName" runat="server"></asp:Label> </div>        
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>
          <asp:Label ID="lblAge" runat="server" Text="Age"></asp:Label></div>
          <div><asp:Label ID="lblPrintAge" runat="server"></asp:Label>        
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>       
    </div>          
  </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

In the code behind on button click, I fetch the data from the database and set the values in the respective controls.

**To do:**
I want to show the popup with the print dialog box i.e. it will show the pop up with the details and a print dialog box to print the popup content. I have checked the net and found that it too opens the pop up with the printable content like this:

```
function PrintPanel() {
    var panel = document.getElementById("<%=pnlPrintContents.ClientID %>");
    var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');
    printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');
    printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    printWindow.document.write(panel.innerHTML);
    printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
    printWindow.document.close();
    setTimeout(function () {
    printWindow.print();
    }, 500);
    return false;
}
```

I only want to show my pop up and do not want to write window.open(..).

Is this possible that on 'Print' button click it shows my div content as a popup with the print dialog box and prints only my div content?

Comment: You can try using modals. Here's a simple link for reference https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

Comment: I want to send the div content on the printer